# SQL - Combining columns of different numbers of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 3 tables that have different data in it. Specifically, different numbers of values for each mainID in each table. What I would like to do is write a query that takes the info from the 3 tables and turns it into the "Final Table" at the bottom.

### Table1

```
mainID      value
------      ------
ID1         Dogs
ID1         Cats
ID1         Elephant
ID1         Snake
ID1         Tiger
ID1         Lamb
ID2         Dogs
ID2         Cats
ID2         Elephant
ID2         Snake
ID2         Tiger
ID2         Lamb
```

### Table2

```
mainID      value
------      ------
ID1         Pencil
ID2         Pencil
```

### Table3

```
mainID      value
------      ------
ID1         Milkshake
ID1         Kool-Aid
ID2         Water
ID2         Soda
```

## Final Table

```
mainID      Table1Value       Table2Value        Table3Value
------      -----------       -----------        -----------
ID1         Dogs              Pencil             Milkshake
ID1         Cats                                 Kool-Aid
ID1         Elephant
ID1         Snake
ID1         Tiger
ID1         Lamb
ID2         Dogs              Pencil             Water
ID2         Cats                                 Soda
ID2         Elephant
ID2         Snake
ID2         Tiger
```

Thank you

Comment: LEFT JOIN is what you need, although how are you choosing to not associate pencil and milkshake with cats? what's your logic or business rule?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Left Join` the `table2` and `table3` with `table1`

Something like this should help you

```
;WITH tab1
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY [mainID] ORDER BY [value]) rn,*
         FROM   Table1),
     tab2
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY [mainID] ORDER BY [value]) rn,*
         FROM   Table2),
     tab3
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY [mainID] ORDER BY [value]) rn,*
         FROM   Table3)
SELECT a.mainID,
       a.value AS Table1Value,
       b.value AS Table2Value,
       c.value AS Table3Value
FROM   tab1 a
       LEFT JOIN tab2 b
              ON a.rn = b.rn
                 AND a.mainID = b.mainID
       LEFT JOIN tab3 c
              ON a.rn = c.rn
                 AND a.mainID = c.mainID
```

**Note :** There no column to the result order so the result order could be little different. If you have any column to order the result add it in `ROW_NUMBER` window function's `Order by`